# Huge error message when using .config

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to learn tkinter and am making a calculator.

I am setting up the buttons and am now trying to change the size of one of them with:

```
Button_back = ttk.Button(Frame1, text='Back', command=printhi) #printhi is temporary.
Button_back.grid(column=0, row=0)
Button_back.config( height = 25, width = 25 )
```

When I try run it the error message is:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Luuk\Python
>PGMs\tkinter\2-1 - Calculator.py", line 75, in <module>
>Button_back.config( Height = 25, width = 25 )

>File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1270, in configure

>return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1261, in
> _configure
>self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, as per every webpage this is what should handle the width and height correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is half right...but there *is* a height option for a `Tkinter` Button, just not a `ttk` Button. If you absolutely need the height option, you can still use a regular Tkinter button, it just won't be as pretty. Also, you can print the dictionary of widget options if you're ever in this bind again by printing `widget.config()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttk


root = tk.Tk()

tk_button = tk.Button(root, text='tkinter button')
ttk_button = ttk.Button(root, text='ttk button')

for key in tk_button.config().iterkeys():
    print('tkinter: ' + key)

for key in ttk_button.config().iterkeys():
    print('ttk: ' + key)

tk_button.pack()
ttk_button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'height' for a button, only width... (Also for other things probably but this is what I know for sure now)

Found this after another half hour search:

http://www-acc.kek.jp/WWW-ACC-exp/KEKB/control/Activity/Python/TkIntro/introduction/button.htm